# All possible results of a modulus?

Tags: java, math, modulus

What are all possible results of the expression `(n % m)`, where `n` and `m` are integer variables?

I thought it was `0` to `(m-1)` but unsure.

Comment: I don't understand your question. There is only one result.. which is.. `n % m`.

Comment: Are they *positive* integers?

Comment: I want to know the range of results that can occur, the range of values that the answer can be of n % m.

Comment: Yes, sorry, assuming they are positive.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because. Other close options are too much work to figure out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question about Java's % operator is on-topic for SO and does not belong on math.stackexchange. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Agreed with GregS that this question is about Java's modulus operator and therefore on-topic. What's the rush to judgement about? Sheesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `m` is a *positive* integer, the range if possible values is `-min(abs(n), m - 1)` through `min(abs(n), m - 1)`, inclusive.

So if `n` is zero or positive and it's greater than `m` (the typical case), the range will be `0` to `m-1` inclusive.

If `n` is zero or negative and its absolute value is greater than `m`, the range will be `-(m-1)` through `0`, inclusive.

In all cases, if `n`'s absolute value is lower than `m`, the bound above set by `m-1` is set by `n` instead. That is, if `n` is zero or positive and less than `m`, the range is `0` to `n`, inclusive (and so on).

Comment: But `n % m` is.. `n % m`.. how the result can be different?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: The question is about the theoretical result across the range of possible values of `n` and `m`.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `n % m` can be in range of ]-m, +m[.

Reason: The definition of modulo operator in java is something like *For all int values n and m the following must always be true: (n / m) x m + (n % m) == n*.

But if n is negative, `(n / m) * m` will always be equal or greater than n, so `n % m` must be negative to fulfill the equation above.

The rule is: *The result of the remainder operation (if non-zero) has always the same sign as the left operand.*

Comment: What if `n` is smaller than `m`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder then the result is simply n itself.

Comment: The version before the edit was correct, why did you change it? `[-m, +m]` is technically correct but not ideal since the result can not be equal to `m` or `-m`.

Comment: @Joni Don't know why the brackets flipped. Was not on purpose. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

lets take examples
for positve n and m your answer is right but here some cases...

```
-1%10=-1
-1%-10=-1
1%-10=1
1%10=1
```

Positive % positive  return values between `0 to m-1`

negative % negative  return values between `0 when n <= m  else it will be between 0 to n+1